# Text inside Math

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I tried doing this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
$x^2 \text{something} y^2$
```

but that just came out like:

> x^2somethingy^2

Anyone know how to fix this issue? I need to have text inside my math environment

Comment: In math mode, spaces are ignored. Thus, you need to supply the spaces *inside* the `\text` command: `$x^2 \text{ something } y^2$`. (The spaces outside the argument of `\text` continue to be ignored, of course.)

Comment: You can also do things like `$x^2\quad\text{something}\quad y^2$`. For example, when I have punctuation at the end of a line of displayed math, I put a `\qquad` before the punctuation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For inline text between inline math expressions it is usually better to just stop and start the math

```
$x^2$ something $y^2$
```

then the interword spacing and line breaking matches the rest of the paragraph.

If that isn't possible then you can put them inside the `\text`

```
$x^2 \text{ something } y^2$
```

But this is essentially like putting the text fragment in `\mbox` so it freezes all white space at its natural size, not allowing any stretch or shrink, and prevents line breaking.